# Trying to pass string values stored from html read method in to a textfield using Selenium

Tags: java, testing, selenium, junit

Here's the method:

```
package com.abstractions.authentication;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadHtml {

private static URL u;
private static Scanner s;
public static String html;

public static String getUrl(String newUrl) throws Exception
{
    u = new URL(newUrl);
    s = new Scanner(u.openStream());

    while (s.hasNext())
    {
        String line = s.nextLine();

        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while (s.hasNext())
            {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = s.nextLine();
            }
            sb.toString();
            html = sb.toString();
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

    return html;
 }
}
```

Here's the test:

```
@Test
public void getHtmlOfUrl() throws Exception
{
    WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();

    browser.navigate().to("https://crimestoppers-uk.org/give-information/give-information-online/");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    String inputHtml = ReadHtml.getUrl("http://www.testforce.co.uk");
    browser.findElement(By.id("tx_desc")).sendKeys(inputHtml);
}
```

Problem: The string value seems to remain null so nothing gets entered in the textfield.

Comment: Are you sure inputHtml is not blank ?

Comment: it is blank, i know where the problem is but dont know how to fix it. i have initialised variable 'html' in the method and am returning that as empty string. the html variable is not picking up the html code which is read inside my 'which' statement. seems to ignore it. sorry, im kinda new to programming.

Comment: ok i think i fixed it. i moved the variable Html inside the method and initialised it just before the return statement as 'String html = sb.toString(). not sure if this is the best way though